# What are those numbers on the door's hinges?

Tags: doors

In the middle of the hinges there is a square bit with a dot on an angle. At the four corners of the hinges, around the square, there are some numbers: -1,0,+1,+2.

Do they mean anything?

Comment: I'm sure they mean something to someone. What's problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Probably just manufacturer's quality tracking indicators, with very little practical value to anyone else.